# Testing share Function across view

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, helper

I create a class "Helper.cshtml" in my App_Code folder that containt some Helper function in order to reuse somme logic accros different view.

Here is the code in my Helper.cshtml class:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Web.Mvc

@functions
{
    public static bool DisplaySectionGestionnaireExterne(string individusParRole)
    {
        if (individusParRole != new RoleIndividuGestionnaireExterne().Code)
            return true;

        return (Model.IsInvestissementInterne || Model.IsInvestissementExterne || Model.IsInvestissementFondsExterne);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to unit test that function, without testing the entire view who use that function?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should ask yourself if this logic belong to the view or not. A rule of thumb is that any logical operation with model data should be considered as business logic and remain outside the view. This way, you could unit test these conditions without problem inside a unit test.

Since it seems that it is a logic that takes an action on the view, I think you might want to have this code with a view model (if you are using view model approach). Your view model could be used by your view by only invoking the `DisplaySectionGestionnaireExterne` that would be the boolean you want to use in your view. The view remains clean and the logic elsewhere.

I know that I am not answering your question directly but testing views requires to have several other objects to be instantiated and add a lot of overwhelming mocking and codes.